# Exposing SQLAlchemy ORM detached entities as domain objects

Tags: python, orm, architecture, sqlalchemy

This is quite a lengthy post so I separated it into the main question, an illustrative example with code and some more context in the end describing my thoughts and problems.

## Question

I'm using detached entities throughout my application. Is this a correct way to expose ORM entities to the rest of the application? If not, what is problematic about it?

## Code (setup)

Database setup:

```
db_conn_string = "sqlite://"
# db_conn_string = "mysql+pymysql://root:root@33.33.33.1:33060/alchemist"
engine = create_engine(db_conn_string)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
```

For the entities I only define the relationship if I eager load them. This is to ensure that when they're being used as detached entities you cannot directly retrieve related entities that are not loaded.

Entities (truncated):

```
class _Base(object):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


Base = declarative_base(cls=_Base)


class Tree(Base):
    type = Column(String(200))

    branches = relationship("Branch", back_populates="tree", lazy='subquery')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Tree(id='{}', type='{}', branches='{}')>".format(self.id, self.type, self.branches)


class Branch(Base):
    name = Column(String(200))

    tree_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tree.id'), nullable=False)
    tree = relationship("Tree", back_populates="branches", lazy='subquery')

    # Not defining leaves since this is not an eager loaded relationship and must be retrieved explicitly.
    # leaves = relationship("Leaf", back_populates="branch")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Branch(id='{}', name='{}', tree_id='{}')>".format(self.id, self.name, self.tree_id)


class Leaf(Base):
    size = Column(Integer)

    branch_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('branch.id'), nullable=False)
    # branch = relationship("Branch")  # Also not eager loaded

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Leaf('{}')>".format(self.size)
```

I provide a repository object to perform basic CRUD operations. The session transaction scope is then managed within a context object around the repository:

```
class RepositoryContext(object):
    def __init__(self, entity_class):
        self.entity_class = entity_class

    def __enter__(self):
        self.session = get_session()
        return CrudRepository(self.entity_class, self.session)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        try:
            self.session.commit()
        except Exception:
            self.session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            self.session.close()


class CrudRepository(object):
    """
    CrudRepository implements (entity agnostic) CRUD operations.
    """

    def __init__(self, entity_class, session):
        self.entity_class = entity_class
        self._session = session

    def retrieve_all(self):
        return self._session.query(self.entity_class).all()

    def retrieve_by(self, **kwargs):
        return self._session.query(self.entity_class).filter_by(**kwargs).one_or_none()

    # Other CRUD methods here.

    def query(self):
        '''To perform custom queries'''
        return self._session.query(self.entity_class)
```

## Code (usage)

So basic usage would look like:

```
with RepositoryContext(Tree) as repo:
    tree = repo.retrieve_by(id=1)
# Session is closed outside of context. tree is a detached instance.
len(tree.branches)  # This is ok, eager loaded
```

If you then want to get leaves for a certain branch we cannot access it using `tree.branches[0].leaves` since that relationship is not defined. Because we don't want to eager load it we have to retrieve it separately which looks like:

```
with RepositoryContext(Leaf) as repo:
    branch = tree.branches[0]
    leaves = repo.query().filter_by(branch_id=branch.id).all()
# Now have leaves related to first branch. Also detached
```

Similarly for updates or refreshing you'd open a context and call the relevant function:

```
with RepositoryContext(Tree) as repo:
    repo.refresh(tree)  # This refreshes the tree state (discarding changes)
```

## Context

For a new project we are using SQLAlchemy ORM but I am unsure how to correctly use the ORM entities.

I've always been taught that the domain model and database details should be separated from each other as much as possible. Yet with an ORM this means that I constantly have to map ORM entities to domain model objects and then back again which defeats the whole point of using ORM in the first place.

Going down the path of using ORM entities within the application I wanted to make sure I don't get unintended side effects. So I created a tight transactional scope to enforce any persistence to be explicitly handled by a repository class. This means I'm using detached entities throughout the application and attaching them within transactions only.

With my current implementation I lose some of the functionality provided by SQLAlchemy. That is accessing related data that has not been eager loaded (eg. From the code example: `branch.leaves` is not defined so you have to add them by specifying branch id).

My apologies if the post is long, I have truncated as much as possible whilst keeping it runnable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are looking for more information / guidelines: Mike Bayer wrote a pretty detailed response to my question at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/u9Igta1CYdo .

Comment: Thanks for posting the follow-up, always appreciated.